# Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have an IntelliJ Android project, that I successfully imported to Android Studio 0.4.0. It works perfectly if I don't change anything in manifest. However, when I want to change the launcher activity and run, it fails with this error:

```
Launching application: com.trackingeng/LandingActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.trackingeng/LandingActivity"  
    -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN  
    cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.trackingeng/LandingActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.trackingeng/LandingActivity} does not exist.
```

When I click **Sync Project with Gradle files**, it outputs:

```
Project Sync
The project 'TrackingEng' is not a Gradle-based project
```

Run settings:
[image]

Comment: Where is your original **AndroidManifest.xml** file?

Comment: In the same place, under main folder in project.

Comment: I mean is this picture in the post is your original `AndroidManifest.xml` or not.

Comment: Yes it is. I have not changed anything after import.

Comment: I have found a thread, hope could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670607/error-type-3-activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: Though not effective in the OP's case, doing a gradle sync solved `Error: Activity class {...} does not exist.` for me.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180185/package-rename-and-error-activity-class-does-not-exist/45912398#45912398

Comment: if you are Android 8 or using google pixel here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670607/error-type-3-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: In my case I missed to run npm start. It solved that issue

Comment: maybe there is no space left on your device ): -> :)

Comment: GO to edit configurations... over there in general tab under that installations options, in that change deploy from nothing to default apk.

Comment: Check whether the following values are same,

package (usually line 2) in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

applicationId (usually line 90) in defaultConfig section of /android/app/build.gradle

Line 1 of /android/app/src/main/java/com/paysack/MainApplication.java

Line 1 of /android/app/src/main/java/com/paysack/MainActivity.java

Comment: Still I am facing this issue , None of the answer resolved my issue, tried all answers

Answer (score 832, accepted):

I faced a similar problem after refactoring.
This is what i did to resolve this issue:

1. Cleaned the Project
2. Deleted the `Build` directory
3. Restarted Android Studio
4. Rebuild the Project
5. Run
6. Optionally (Go to the files menu on android, click on "Invalidate Caches / Restart..." uninstall the app on your phone and try again)

And everything worked fine!
I think the key is to **restart your IDE**.

**Edit 1:**
If the above steps don't work for you, then deleting `Gradle cache` seems to be a solution, as pointed out by @Yasitha.

**Edit 2**
As suggested by a couple of users in the comments below, sometimes the issue can be resolved by completely removing and reinstalling the app from your device.
Simply type `adb uninstall <package>` in terminal to completely remove app from the device.

**Edit 3**
As mentioned in [Abhishek's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59751468/634958), one should also try deleting the app from your device in case multiple users are set up on your device.
Simply go to  `Mobile Settings > Apps > [Your App] > More > Uninstall App for All Users`

**Edit 4**
As mentioned by [Yassin Ajdi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59751468/634958), executing the `uninstallAll` Gradle task can also fix the issue.
You can go to `Gradle > Tasks > Install > uninstallAll` to get the job done.

**UPDATE for Android Studio 2.1 and up**

When running Android Studio 2.1 and up you can also encounter this issue when you have the instant run option enabled in your preferences (is enabled by default).

To disable this option go to the `Preferences` option in the `Android Studio` top menu and look for `Instant Run` so you can uncheck the first checkbox on that screen.

[image: Disable Instant Run in Android Studio 2.1+]

Anyway that fixed it for me. Originally pointed out by user @yusufonder. I discovered this was the issue since `gradle install` still worked.

Comment: It works fine even without deleting the build directory.

Comment: I had do delete gradle cache as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25602161/630833

Comment: The perfect (and unique) solution for me. I have a dynamic application id in my build.gradle (`applicationId "com.example."+ CLIENT_ID)`) in order to manage several clients' customization and everytime I changed the value of the variable I wasn't able to launch the app. Beer for you man!

Comment: Though this is a late entry, but i am facing this problem only after updating Android Studio to 1.5 and the above solution doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @shah, Android 1.5.1 -> facing the same issue.  Above solution does not work

Comment: I had to delete the build directory coz a generated jar had my previous package name.

Comment: deleting gradle cache seems to be the work around after trying steps given above.

Comment: Did all the above -- remove build directories, .gradle cache, invalidate/restart, turn off auto run, clean build.  What finally worked was to re-sync gradle as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155938/android-studio-gets-package-name-wrong-when-running-apk/29862639#29862639

Comment: (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻ I had to clear the 'App Trash' on my device.

Comment: I had this same issue after upgrading my device to Oreo. I'm still not sure what ultimately caused the issue but completely removing the app from the device and rebooting the device after performing all of the steps listed above (clean build and restart Android Studio) resolved the issue for me.

Comment: @smg you should add this as an answer, also was the only thing that fixed it for me.

Comment: I've also run into this many times. I follow the instructions above and often switch devices too. Sometimes when I have a physical device connected it still fails after doing the prescribed steps. So i'll run it on an emulator it which works fine then reconnect the other device. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Try to execute 'adb uninstall <package>' in terminal to completely remove app from device

Comment: I have same problem. Nothing worked for me. Clean, restart, delete cache. The main issue was multi-user in handset. Removed app from other user and worked

Comment: File - Sync Project with Gradle file was the only thing that worked for me

Comment: Hit "Refresh all gradle projects" button from the "Gradle" tab from the right (I am running Android Studio 3.1.2)

Comment: On Android 7.0 when you uninstall the app on device (by dragging it to "Uninstall" label on the device main screen), the app in fact just "disabled". You need to go to Settings/Apps and manually remove the app from there (alternatively use ADB command). I bounce into it couple of times, but after a few mouths I get forgetting about this Android 7.0 so called feature.

Comment: Xiaomi Mix 2 phone. 
When trying to uninstall an app I noticed it would uninstall properly, but it would also remain installed on the "Second Space" (Switch app) native to the phone. When removing the app from the second space -> Clean project in Android Studio & install again. It works!

Comment: cleaning and then building my project helped.

Comment: Yes, cleaning project and restarting Android Studio does the trick for me too

Comment: i have this **[error type 3
Error: Activity class{} does not exist ]** problem only in OnePlus A3003 device , rest in another device my app run and work perfectly. now how can i solve this issue ?

Comment: @AjayCodes this can happen if the device has multiple user accounts on it. Going to the app menu in the settings, one can uninstall the app for all users.

Comment: Sometimes it was caused due to errors while building with enabled Instant Run. After disabling that, it was able to run but sometimes still caused same issue. In that case I followed the approach of deleting the gradle cache.

Comment: I had this issue and none of the above worked for me - however what did fix it was totally installing from the device. 
Not just by hitting uninstall - but going into phone settings, going to apps, and then 'Uninstall for ALL users'

Comment: `adb uninstall <package_name>` worked for me! Btw, here package name is the one that goes like `com.android.example.appname`.

Comment: @PriteshVishwakarma did you try to uninstall the package using adb?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan there was two user in one device. i solved this problem by uninstalling app manually.now i able to launch my app successfully.

Comment: Thanks to @NJ, on my Redmi device.. I created a Second space,. And then moved First Space. And then onwards, when i run apps from Android studio it shows App installed but it never appeared on screen. After a lot of struggle I find (NJ) comment. And then checked Second space, I see Android studio ran apps installed on Second space. I just deleted Second space. And restarted device. Solved the issue.

Comment: deleting the build folder worked for me. Invalidates caches and restart didn't work.

Comment: I have faced a few times this isssue and to me used to be enough the steps  6, 1 and 5:
1. Files -> invalidate caches/ restart
2. Clean Project
3. Run / debug

Comment: I faced the same issue uninstall is just uninstalling for the current user. After uninstalling for all users it started working. Thanks a ton !

Comment: This issue can also be caused by the Emulator being locked. Enter the pin to unlock the emulator and try running the app again.

Comment: In my situation I had manually deleted my app from my physical android device and when I tried to rerun it from command line, I got the error.  The error was a result of the app still being installed on the device globally, so I went to settings > apps > selected the app and deleted it.  Once I did that, it was all good.

Comment: Mobile Settings > Apps > [Your App] > More > Uninstall App for All Users  worked for me

Comment: "Build -> Clean Project" and then "Build -> Rebuild Project" works for me.

Comment: Strangely for me, the app does install on my device, and when it is hanging with this error message if I simply open it myself on the android device by clicking the app icon, it goes as normal. I think I need to factory reset my phone.

Comment: Cleaning gradle cache from command line worked for me

Answer (score 379):

Sometimes when testing on a device, *the app doesn't uninstall properly*. To verify and fix this:

1. Go to **Settings**.
2. Go to **Apps**.
3. Select your app. *(here, you can verify that your app is not uninstalled properly)*.
4. Open the overflow menu on the top right and select **Uninstall for all users**.
5. Done. Try to install then launch your app again.

Comment: Using Android O developer preview 3, I could not perform the Uninstall for all users action, as it told me that the app did not exist in apps list. Running `adb uninstall {packageName}` solved the problem.

Comment: For emulator, Ankit's answer did not work. I had deleted my app from the launcher, but it remained on the system, which caused the problem. I had to use this method to uninstall it completely.

Comment: thnx man i was facing this problem on android oreo where application is not uninstalled success fully

Comment: This was exactly my problem, app was not installed for this user. Just uninstalled it by the procedure mentioned above and it started to work

Comment: my app was disabled

Comment: I created an issue on the [official tracker for this problem](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135376049). Please star it to draw attention to the need of Google to fix this issue.

Comment: I had the same issue, I had a work profile on that device and for some reason the app was installed on both. After uninstall for both profiles I was able to install from Android Studio

Comment: I had the same issue. However, I couldn't uninstall the app following step #4. I had to do it using ADB `adb uninstall [package_name]`. Thanks @Nicks !

Comment: What helped me was just go into the Play Store on the device and even though I deleted the app, it still showed the option "Delete" there. After pressing that button it all worked.

Answer (score 124):

I would face this problem when uninstalling the app via the device (i.e. dragging the app to the "Uninstall" option). But here is the proper way to uninstall:

Use the `./gradlew uninstallAll` command. This will prevent the `Error: Activity class {HomeActivity} does not exist.` error.

**Update:**

If you’re lazy you can use the abbreviation for this task:  `./gradlew uA`.

Or define aliases for common gradle tasks in your `.bash_profile`, doing so will save time, typing, and you won’t have to remember every command nor worry about typos. I suggest doing this.

Comment: Bad as that was I still think it was better.  Gradle is an abomination IMO.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me with Android Studio 3.1 Canary 7.

Comment: great answer. Some devices seems to have a problem with uninstall. For me, it is Xiaomi Mi Mix 2 with EU Build. I guess it is a error in Build version of device.

Comment: This works for  me. After running ./gradlew uninstallAll

Comment: @Shanison , don’t forget that you can add aliases for all these different useful commands that we all forget. Just open you’re `.bash_profile` and add aliases for the commands you use all the time. This way you won’t have to type as much nor worry about memorizing all the different commands and spelling (me no gud at spellin).

Comment: This one did the trick after I uninstalled the app on the device. Also, you can make a small shortcut to uninstall your app. Just create an empty `.txt` file and paste the following line: `C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe uninstall com.myapp.packagename`. Then rename this `.txt` file to `.bat` and you can run it every time you want to uninstall your app (on Windows)

Comment: Thanks man, it worked for Android Studio 4.0.1

Comment: Worked for me after converting groovy to kts on 2020.1.1 canary 10

Comment: You made my day, man! Best answer on earth! ;)

Comment: No, thank you to ya'll. Happy coding.

Answer (score 79):

I had the same issue and this is how I fixed it:

Go to `Gradle > Tasks > Install > uninstallAll`

[image]

Comment: This works for me too. But why the issue happens and how `uninstallAll` would resolve? Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. Please explain how this would resolve the issue?

Comment: If you could not find the uninstallAll  option  in gradle side bar. Click run anything(gradle icon) then search for uninstallAll.

Comment: For those who do not know where to access this panel is, it is in top right side of your screen.

Answer (score 74):

This happens when you do the following

- connect your device/emulator
- run the app from Android Studio (AS)
- use/test the app and uninstall it from the device while it is still
  connected to your computer
- try to run the app again from AS

AS thinks you still have the app in your device.

tl;dr - To resolve this, you can simply disconnect your device after uninstalling the app and reconnect it.

Comment: Though don't let yourself get confused if the app doesn't show up in the Launcher, just check settings/Apps -> "All" if the app is listed. That was the case with my application, and after removing it, everything worked fine again.

Comment: If it does not appear in the Launcher as @DanielGilbert said, you can easily uninstall with "adb uninstall package.name". This worked for me too.

Comment: This worked for me too. I was running a sample project, which has two versions. I installed the first version, and then uninstalled it to install the second version. I have wasted a lot of time to fix the error. This is not the first time that Android development had this kind of weird, unsolvable issues...

Comment: My case. Disconnect and connect device - this worked for me! The app was not on the device, but AS didn't install it thinking that the app is still in my device

Answer (score 61):

The App is already installed for Another user. Please try to uninstall the same app for all the user. Then try.

Or you can try after running adb command.

```
adb uninstall PACKAGE_NAME
```

where PACKAGE_NAME is the full name such as com.example.myapp

Comment: This works! in my case `adb uninstall com.demo` where my app name was `demo`

Comment: com.demo  will be your package name

Comment: The only answer that worked! Android Studio 3.4.2, API Level 28

Answer (score 30):

I had the same error after renaming/refactoring. What I did was add the `applicationId` property attribute to my build.gradle file, and set its value to the application package.

In **build.gradle**:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"  
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, explain how to add applicationId to buidl.gradle !

Comment: You could also add application ID to module settings of application as an alternative

Answer (score 25):

In my case i uninstalled application from phone it after that the problem began but, the below command worked for me.

Execute below command in terminal/cmd

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

package_name something like com.example.applicationname
Then, try to reinstall the application. It should work.

Comment: This worked for me since I had previously installed the apk via adb, but somehow uninstalling it via the phone's app manager left some app traces.

Comment: This worked for me. For multiple devices: 

adb -s <device ID> uninstall <package name>

Comment: To get the list of devices use the following command:
```$/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
```
to get list of devices (something like 'VQM0218126001101' or 'emulator-5555' ) and then:
```$/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s <device_ID> uninstall  "com.<xxxxx>.<xxxx>"```
And wait for `Success` result string.

Answer (score 24):

This happened to me using react-native run-android because my package name did not match my app ID. Just add `--appId YOUR_APP_ID`.

Comment: This happened to be my problem, the package name was renamed, but the folder structure didn't follow the pattern.

````PackageName com.{biz_name}.{app.name}
     Folder structure was just com.{app.name}````

Comment: This became an issue for me after upgrading react native from 0.61.5 to 0.62.2, my app id has never matched my package name, but after the upgrade I need to add --appId YOUR_APP_ID (note it's --appId not app-id).

Comment: After spending hours trying all the different ways to uninstall etc. from the other answers, this simply fixed the problem. I also ran into it upgrading to RN 0.62.x. What could have changed in the config files to make this necessary?

Answer (score 21):

### Try changing the name of the Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Right now it says:

```
<activity android:name="LandingActivity" >
```

Try either **adding a period** to the beginning of the Activity's name:

```
<activity android:name=".LandingActivity" >
```

Or **adding the package name** to the beginning of the Activity's name:

```
<activity android:name="com.trackingeng.LandingActivity" >
```

*It also may be a problem that your package name has only two components separated by periods (your package name is "com.trackingeng"; a more standard package name would be "com.trackingeng.app")*

Comment: @Siavash except it's not Correct™

Comment: How so @dcow? The accepted answer here didnt work for me, but this one did.

Comment: Which one? adding a dot or a 3-level name?

Answer (score 20):

Follow Steps Below
Go to
Mobile setting > Apps > Your App > More > Hit Uninstall app for all users.

Reason : Because you are having multiple users in your phone and you had uninstalled that app for only one.

Answer (score 15):

I think another reason that issue happen is that it is not fully deleted for all users on the device.

Go to Settings -> Apps - > Your Apps -> Click to the 3 dots on the top right -> Uninstall for all users

It works for me. It happen especially you change the icons of the app or messing around with the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I can't believe this worked. I had 2 accounts on my device and it was installed for the other user.

Comment: yeah it is a bit annoying but it normally happen when the app is under development cause you might want to change loading icons and stuff etc.

Answer (score 13):

For me, the problem was that `AndroidStudio` *thought* that the app was still on the device.

To fix it:

1. **restart the `adb` daemon**; in a terminal or command prompt, enter:

   ```
   adb kill-server
   adb start-server
   ```
2. try to launch your app.
3. if it still doesn't work, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36372901/2898715).

make sure the `platform-tools` of the *Android SDK* is added to your *system path variables*!

Answer (score 12):

When I got this problem I always try this solution and it works.

```
Instant Run disable 

Build -> Clean Project

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

But I found an exception this once. This solution doesn't work for me. Then I find out the problem is Emulator cash. I just do `Wipe data` and `Cold boot now` and the problem is solved.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Below command worked for me. Sometime partial uninstallation of the app also causes this.

Execute below command in terminal/cmd

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

Then, try to reinstall the application. It should work.

Answer (score 10):

Try this from terminal

```
gradlew uninstallAll
```

This will uninstall all the debug, release, apks of all the versions of your app. And re-install the application

Answer (score 9):

On Android 6, when I uninstalled the app it actually went to disabled instead of being removed from device.

Settings > Apps > click on your app and uninstall

Comment: That works, but some more points. If you delete it via adb it doesn't guarantee that problem is solved, event if you don't see this package via adb pm. You have to do it with hands, find it in Settings->App and choose Delete for all users. After that you can install it again

Answer (score 8):

Some times application install on Guest user on your mobile, So try to switch Guest and uninstall the application.

In addition, try to execute the following command to uninstall application
adb uninstall package "Your package Name"

Answer (score 8):

`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was because the app I was trying to launch was installed for a different user on the device. Go to Settings -> Apps (All apps) and and select the app. Click on the overflow menu and select "Uninstall for all users".

Comment: This happened to e too and I had to go to Settings> Apps and Notifications> App info. Had to "Uninstall for all users" and install again.

Comment: I came across the same issue and probably the answer should be updated with this solution as well

Comment: This error occurred to me when I configured multiple build types in my project.

Answer (score 7):

Be warned that if you have multiple Profiles set on the device, your app might already exist in one of the other Profiles.

Uninstalling the app from all the Profiles resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

I use Android Studio 3.2 Beta 5, faced with the same issue

Go to

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

Solved problem for me

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes this happens once you rename the project's root directory, just delete the `.idea` folder of your project and reopen it with Android Studio.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was a very specific problem, I've got a **Lg g5** to test my application on, and to reset my apps data I uninstalled it on the phone, but the phone has a "nice" feature to don't uninstall apps immediatly so you might can reinstall them within one day.
So the app was installed but not usable(**disabled**) after removing the app from the phone completely it worked.

Comment: Worked for me. LG G6 has the same "feature" - I didn't find the way to disable it.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case anyone runs into my issue and has no luck with the other solutions...
I was trying to start an activity through adb for FireTV while debugging Amazon launcher integration. However, my project had 60 different build variants (multi-platform, multi-app project) and the ApplicationId didn't match any classpath since the runtime package (and classpaths) were different from the applicationId.

I was trying to run
`adb shell am start -n com.myappid.example.packageone.packagetwo/com.myappid.example.packageone.packagetwo.MySplashActivity`

(Of course I had tried many combinations with `com.runtimepath.example`  since I had the added challenge of a different applicationId in my build.gradle and another at runtime)

What finally helped was this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/36255727/5970652

Which revealed a different format! 
`com.myappid.example/com.runtimepath.example.packageone.packagetwo.MySplashActivity`

So if you have a different runtime classpath try specifying with the build.gradle applicationId before the slash and the runtime classpath afterwards.

You can also get these values from `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` and `this.getLocalClassName()` respectively if you want to log them in logcat.

Comment: This was exactly my problem! I was frustrated for a while, but once I put the app package name before the slash, and the fully qualified package/class name after the slash it worked.

Answer (score 6):

In my case there was next reason:

I have 2 users: me and Guest.
and app was installed on both of them but deleted only at first.

when I switched to Guest screen and delete app from there, app installed ok.

hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 6):

If you have uninstalled the application manually from the device and you have multi user set up, this error could happen. The application needs to be uninstalled from all the users in the device.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: If you have multiple users, it can be found in  notification drawer in the home screen (It'll be there along with the settings icon). Otherwise, go to the settings page and go to System->Multiple Users and click that user. After logging into the other user, the app can be uninstalled.

Comment: i had copy off app installed in "work profile" in samsung s9+, uninstalling all copies of the app worked out.

Answer (score 6):

I have a Samsung Galaxy. Searching in the settings above didn't work because it didn't show up at all in my Apps settings.

I found the application on my phone by typing the name of the app in the search field. I realized it was in the "Work"(using Mobile@Work) profile and removed it. You can find the settings for the profile by going to Settings->Work profile->Apps

I hope this helps somebody who may not find it the same way that many of the other answers stated it could be found in the settings.

Comment: OMG thank man, you saved my day. Same problem with fckn samsung

Comment: and the same with an LG G6 after a day of developing... surely saved me a lot of time with this one!

Answer (score 6):

Faced this problem in android studio 3.5.1 Took me a day to solve this problem,Tried everything including cleaning cache,restart and renaming package name as well. So if any of above did't work than try this.

Just go to gradle > Tasks > Install > UninstallAll

Here is the link:
[Error type 3: Activity Class {...} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670607/error-type-3-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 6):

Gradle -> Tasks -> Install -> Uninstall All.

Comment: This one works for me :D

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 5):

Even I had the same problem but none of the above solutions worked for me.
The problem was that, I had froze the particular app which I was trying to run via Titanium Backup due to which I got the above error. I tried both in Eclipse and Android Studio.

After the realization I just uninstalled the app and then ran it again.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to share the trick that helped in my case. I uninstalled the application from the device and nothing of clean/rebuild/Android Studio restart operations didn't help.

Since Android Studio thinks that the application is still installed on the device and doesn't deploy it, you can force the installation using the ADB:

```
adb install -r <your_application_from.apk>
```

where `-r` means reinstall the app, keeping its data.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I actually change the package name, and it started causing this issue.

I have tried many trick but here I am describing what actually worked for me.

1. Delete your build folder it also includes the clean(so no need to clean it)
2. Try to restart android studio if this doesn't work then invalidate the cache too.
3. if it still give you error then try to wipe out the data of your emulator, hopefully this will resolve the issue,

Make sure your activity name is correct also make sure the package name is correct in manifest file.

Comment: 100% Working i tried first 2 method thanks

Answer (score 4):

Refactor the activity launcher and change the class name.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below steps:

1. Clean your Project
2. Delete your build directory
3. Restart your Android Studio
4. Rebuild the project

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same problem somewhere in the past. *Such problems actually occurs when we do some refactoring like - renaming, moving files within the project etc.* Renaming and Moving files require changes in the gradle file so whenever you rename or move some file just clean the project:

> Build -> Clean Project

Cleaning the project just removes the **.class** files and recompiles the project. Basically, it forces a project rebuild.

Sometimes such types of errors did not cleaned on cleaning project then try to uninstall the app from the device (either it is emulator or physical one) and run the app again. Hope this will help you, it helps me 50% times.

**Note:-** *Whenever you got any error just don't go to google, Clean the project if this not work do what you want to google.*

Answer (score 4):

I have LG Stylus and in my test phone, application isn't remove permanently. In Settings -> Application I found debug app (which I try install and debug by AS) with adnotation turn-off. When I remove app from my phone, error disappeard.

Comment: This does not seem lie an answer to me.

Answer (score 4):

If your app is not installed at device (tested on Android 9) already:

1. Build apk
2. Move apk to device and install it
3. Return to Android Studio and press Run to launch app

Comment: This was also the case for me running Android 11 simulator on Apple Silicon (M1 chip) using arctic fox beta.  Tried EVERYTHING on this forum.  In the end noticed apk was being created in the app/build/output folder; so I used adb install -t path/to/apk.apk. After that subsequent attempts to run & debug from within android studio worked!  Seems to happen every-time I upgrade AS / change machines.. *facepalm

Answer (score 3):

I had Error type 3. I managed to fix it by adding the following code below in AndroidMainfest.xml.

```
    <activity android:name=".GameActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Worked for me as I upgrade compile sdk version from 31 to 33

Answer (score 3):

**Remove the app** in Android machine.

That works for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you test your app on a smartphone, which has 24 hours secure app remove (like LG G6) you have to uninstall app manually in settings, because it is in bin for 24 hours after uninstalling, so Android Studio thinks that app is installed, but it is in app thrash on your smartphone.

Answer (score 3):

I had been playing with [Android Work Profiles](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7029561?hl=en) by making use of the [Shelter App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.typeblog.shelter) - I had copied my own application into the work profile.

I had to remove my app from both the regular profile as well as the work profile, and then the app would launch properly.  Somehow the existing package inside the work profile was getting in the way of the IDE deploy.

Comment: thank you so much, i disabled the work profile, then enabled it again, and the app was under apps from work profile, uninstall it then ran flutter run and it works!

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurred due to my **Emulator**. My emulator was running in **SafeMood**.

Restarting my Emulator without **SafeMood** worked. First it was started in SafeMood automatically and problem occurred. Then when I disable SafeMood and restart my Emulator it did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

I resolve the problem by
Edit Condifiguration -> Deploy-> Select default apk
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xuLG.png

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

I encountered the "Activity class {} does not exist" error in my Android app after uninstalling the old version. The situation was unique as the app was uninstalled for all users, and **my device (OnePlus 6T) denied/block my app's package name.** After trying various solutions and internet suggestions, I found a workaround that resolved the issue.

**Solution:**

If you're facing a similar issue and other solutions haven't worked, consider trying the following steps:

Navigate to your Flutter project's android folder using the command line.
`cd android`. then
Run the command
`./gradlew uninstallAll`.
This command uninstalls the app from all users on your device and can help resolve issues related to package name conflicts and missing activity classes.

It's important to note that this solution may not be conventional, but it worked for me in a situation where other methods failed. Keep in mind that debugging can sometimes lead to unconventional solutions.

I hope this helps others who might encounter this unique scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Build > Rebuild Project

Answer (score 2):

I had a version of the app on the device that could not be uninstalled as it was corrupt somehow. I had to factory reset the device.

Answer (score 2):

I took reference from [@jayeffkay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist?page=1&tab=votes#comment49041301_24241687):

> I had do delete gradle cache as described here [Android Studio gets package name wrong when running .apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155938/android-studio-gets-package-name-wrong-when-running-apk/25602161#25602161)

It works for me after I deleted the gradle cache files located in:

```
/your_proj_directory/.gradle/2.10
```

2.10 is the gradle version used in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Disable instant run for Android Studio (tested on version 2.1.1)

Answer (score 2):

I changed a NDK, and problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not careful and you're trying to disable something in your app manifest make sure you don't disable the app...

```
<application
android:allowBackup="false"
android:enabled="true"
...
```

I accidentally set `enabled` to "false" instead of `allowBackup`. Wasted 2 hours searching for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

**My solution is: close the "instant run" of android studio.**

"instant run" can be found with the following steps:
Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run

and then uncheck the checkbox "Enable Instant Run to hot swap...."

Answer (score 2):

If your app has only two word package name like[**com.example**] then all your class must be mentioned with full path in manifest like [**com.example.SplashActivity**] instead of relative path like[**.SplashActivity**]
change this and delete all your build folder and re-run app.

Answer (score 2):

Go to module settings -> Falvors -> Application id ->
(Add your package name)

Comment: For Android Studio 3.2 . Go to File => Project Structure => App under Module section => select falvors from tab bar. Change or re-write even your package is correctly indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Just doing a clean build did the trick for me.

To do a clean build, do:

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

Then do a build or straight run on device.

Answer (score 2):

For me, on Android Studio 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04, I met the same issue.
This happens when my colleague changed the package name, and it is okay on his machine.
Neither clean project nor rebuild project work.

I use Sync project with gradle files button on the top pannel of Android Studio and everything works well.

Answer (score 2):

Got to `android/app/build.gradle` and search for

```
 buildTypes {
     ....
 }
```

You might have something like

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
    }
    release {
        ...
    }
    customBuildType {
        ...
    }
}
```

Chose the `buildType` you want to start and then start the App the following

```
react-native run-android --variant=[buildType] --appIdSuffix '[buildType]'
```

So,

```
react-native run-android --variant=debug --appIdSuffix 'debug'
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep package name same in manifest file and in build.gradle(Module:app).it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried same app with different device it worked. Finally I noticed that the application is disabled:

1. Go to setting/apps (on the phone)
2. If it is disabled, remove it

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the app has not been uninstalled properly.

Use the below plugin of Android Studio to uninstall the app from the device [in case you were unable to find your app inside the settings of the device]

ADBIdea: https://github.com/pbreault/adb-idea

ADBIdea adds the following ADB commands to Android Studio and Intellij:

- ADB Uninstall App
- ADB Kill App
- ADB Start App
- ADB Restart App
- ADB Clear App Data
- ADB Clear App Data and Restart
- ADB Revoke Permissions
- ADB Start App With Debugger
- ADB Restart App With Debugger

There are two basic ways to invoke a command:

Through the Tools->Android->ADB Idea menu
By searching for "ADB" in "Find Actions"

- Mac OS X: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: I uninstalled my app from the device homescrenn. After your answer, I checked the applications list and the app is still there and marked as like "not uninstalled from other users"... So deleted the app completely from my device solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I face this problem after rename my package...

so simplest one is go to File-> Invalidate caches/Restart ....

Answer (score 2):

That might also happen if you have by mistake two launcher Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityB">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Just leave the correct one LAUNCHER Activity

Answer (score 2):

Besides the cases that the first upvoted comment provided, there is another case can cause this error: the output apk file cannot be replaced by Android Studio, you can manually delete it and build again, it should work.

If you did not change the output path, the default apk output path is `{Your Project Path}/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I don't know why, the smartphone was blocking my app. To solve it I went to Configuration --> Application , found my app and pressed "Unistall". I went to configuration becouse my application was not appearing on menu.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, this problem can be caused by an attached device/emulator while uninstalling the app and AS connection still exists.  On my end, I just delete all the **build** folders (under app and project dirs) in the project, and relaunch the application on the device/emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are building hidden version. That’s intended behavior for hidden app.

If you want to build regular version, you need to change Build Variant in Android Studio **Build > Select Build Variant**, change it to regular.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new project from an existing project:

build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxx" //xxxxxxxxx should be "package name (com.demo.app) from AndroidMenifest.xml" 
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3.0.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
}
```

then click sync in Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by simply deleting the `app -> build`  folder and then rebuilding the project. The build folder is automatically recreated after the project is built so there's no risk in deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

This fix worked for me:

1. Remove the installed debug APK from your phone
2. In Android Studio, go to Build, choose Build APK(s)
3. Put this generated APK on your phone and launch it
4. Exit this app and try to debug your app again from Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs when you uninstalling the App you are developing. Check whether you have activated the guest account, if so switch the account and uninstall the app, switch back to Admin user (You). and carry on!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had defined `defaultConfig` two times.

I don't know why but double check it in case of a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

My package name was like "barisciftci.**PatternApplier**". So changing it to all lowercase solved my problem, so now it looks as "barisciftci.patternapplier".

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly added extra empty `<application>` tag in `AndroidMenifest.xml` which was causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error while developing an instant app then go to Device Settings -> Apps and clear the instant app from device.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the virtual device and re-download it (tested on Android Studio 3.1.3, January 2019).

Answer (score 1):

I read all the 'Run' Log and there I saw this line:

```
"Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space"
```

My problem was, no internal free space to install the app. So, I deleted some files and app get installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was being caused by ndk abiFilters when compiling for arm.
To fix it I had to add the following 'splits' section to app/build.gradle's android block:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism
        reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string
        include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "armv7l"
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Comment: Check whether the following values are same,

package (usually line 2) in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

applicationId (usually line 90) in defaultConfig section of /android/app/build.gradle

Line 1 of /android/app/src/main/java/com/paysack/MainApplication.java

Line 1 of /android/app/src/main/java/com/paysack/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Issue was caused by uninstalling the app while the device was still plugged in.
What happens is the device disables the app rather than removing it.

1. Go to your app list on your device and uninstall the app from there. You will see that it is currently marked as disabled. This is why you cannot run the app because Android Studio fails to install it as it thinks it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm solving simply **(don't delete build folder)**:

1. deleting all files *.apk in
   "\yourapp\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices"
2. running the app compare a popup message "Application Installation
   failed" "Do you want to uninstall the existing application?" click
   Ok
3. rebuild the project
4. run again the project

Answer (score 1):

I got this error. What I tried to fix the error (didn't work) were:

- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project
- Restart Android Studio

Solution was simple , just uninstall the app on your Emulator/Phone and hit "Run" on Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This worked on Android Studio version 4.0.1:

1. Change my git branch to the master branch
2. Return to my own branch

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue and I think the solution is very simple than what I think it was
just go to your manifest and change the package name than copy the same package name into your application iD in the Gradle

`defaultConfig { applicationId "your package name here" }`
that's it, good luck

Answer (score 1):

Check the following in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
      android:name="[your_package_name].MainApplication"
   ...>
    <activity
        android:name="[your_package_name].MainActivity"
       ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this - none of the others worked for me. Click Wipe Data as in screenshot below - it's an issue with the emulator.

[image: wipe data]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with the new Android Studio electric eel optional flags when invalidate cache and restart

Go to `file - invalidate caches...`

Check all boxes, android studio will restart

[image]

This worked for me.

If still does not work

- Check AndroidManifest for the `<activity>` tag and change its package name to `com.yourpackage.YourActivity`
- Check applicationId in build gradle to match your same package
- Go to build - clean project - rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I switched to guest profile in my emulator. I switched back to owner profile and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check Application id in the Gradle file. I had the same issue because I accidentally changes application id while refactoring views name.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was no space left on your device.

Answer (score 0):

The file name of the SharedPreferences must be suffixed with the name of the current flavor to prevent the active compilation variant of a product from accessing the preferences of defined users
for another active compilation with the same preference name.

Although each compilation package is different, it may be that when using `flavorDimensions`, access to user preferences is being crossed and get the *Error type 3 while launching MainActivity*

```
app.getSharedPreferences("${BuildConfig.FLAVOR}_shared_pref_3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

After all these solve suggestions i still had not solved my this problem. And then i remembered my phone has 2 ANDROID User Interface. One of them is using in casual, another is private things of yours. When i download my projects to phone, downloads both of them. I deleted my project in casual one but had not private one. Everything works fine when i delete the private one. So If you have 2 android ui, you should delete all of them and download again.

Answer (score 0):

a simple hack is to rename your package : eg MainActivity to ApplicationMainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, with a much newer version of Android Studio (version 4.1) . A fresh install of Android Studio + a fresh "basic Activity" template would run into error type 3 for hours. I am on win 10 - my problem was how to kill the `gradle` cache. A good answer above showed a screen snapshot from `gradle`, but i didn't find it in Android Studio 4.1. Also the env vars for `gradle` had not been set , and the commandline for `gradle` didn't work. So .. here is how it worked finally. I went to `C:\Users\myusername\ .gradle`. This has `subdir` "caches". I deleted everything inside. Worked !  I did close Android Studio before, restarted and then it worked nicely.  Ah forgot one thing- i run the device emulator (defauöt device), i.e. no physical device yet.

Answer (score 0):

Happen to me when changing app name.. Uninstalled app, switched from debug to release version, installed release and then switched back to debug version and working.

Answer (score 0):

You might have renamed the initial package name & application id.
In that case

```
./adb shell am start -n <your application id>/<Your-full-package-name-as mentioned in the top of manifest>.<launch actibity>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the emulated phone had a pin set and was **currently screen locked** even though not visually apparent. After I unlocked the phone the error went away. `Android Studio 2022.3.1`

What made it confusing is that after pressing play it would build, succeed building, then show the *does not exist* error. It never opened up the *Running Devices* pane like normal. Even after I opened said pane, clicked play again, same process occurred and the phone never appeared to turn on.  So I assumed other problems were at the core as listed in this SO. Finally after clicking the power button for the emulated phone, the screen revealing the hidden culprit showed the screen lock screen. It seemed to be a somewhat ambiguous error.