# Activity class {.....SplashActivity} does not exist

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I got these error while run project on device:

```js
Launching application:.Splash_Activity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n ".Splash_Activity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=.Splash_Activity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {.Splash_Activity} does not exist.
```

I check my Android-Manifest file it is like

```js
 <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        
</activity>
```

and Gradle is like:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-3.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar')
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

I also try so much by changing the package name and so on..
What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: `SplashActivity` this is your class name of splash screen.

Comment: Yes, it also open if i press ctr button and click on the name of it in AndroidManifest file

Comment: Can you post the whole manifest coding.

Comment: What's your correct class name spelling? In the logcat it shows `.Splash_Activity` (with underscore) and in your manifest `SplashActivity` (without underscore).

Answer (score 8):

2018... make sure the device has the app completely uninstalled.
Go to your Apps in your settings and delete the reference to the app your trying to install.

Comment: i had the same problem. I had to run adb uninstall to fix the problem

Answer (score 7):

To resolve this issue:

1. Clean the Project
2. Deleted the Build directory
3. Restart Android studio
4. Rebuild the Project
5. Run

I think the key is to restart your IDE.

Or
Try adding

```
com.package.name.SplashActivity
```

Here change the package name accordingly

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: Can you try second alternate mentioned in answer

Comment: i did that too i also add splashsctivity name in EditConfiguration and make it launch activity there but doesn't work

Comment: One more thing needed before all this is to delete the app for all users if it is already installed on device.

Answer (score 3):

If **app was installed before** then you need to be sure app deleted for all users. (Old versions of Android cause that error.)

You could check it from phone **Settings -> Apps and Notifications -> Application Informations -> Your App Name** then click delete for all users button from right up corner menu.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and i try this fix it.

1. file -> Invalidata Caches
2. uninstall app and reinstall