# Can't compile an extern project

Tags: android, gradle

I retrieved a project from someone else and I'm supposed to work on it. i'm not very familiar with gradle and all the builds, but I've done the classic solutions and my problem still remains.

Here is the error I get when I try to run the project :

> Error while executing: am start -n
>   "com.nouveal.note/com.nouveal.note.ui.activities.MainActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.nouveal.note/.ui.activities.MainActivity } Error type 3 Error:
>   Activity class
>   {com.nouveal.note/com.nouveal.note.ui.activities.MainActivity} does
>   not exist.
>
> Error while Launching activity

I did put `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in my build.gradle as recommanded on other posts but still get this mistake.

I also get few lines of warning (that somehow disappear once the error is here) that says :

- warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come up with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern.class format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any -target type options.

I'm really lost on how to fix this, any help appreciated...

EDIT : There is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nouveal.note" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

     <compatible-screens>
         <!--&lt;!&ndash;all small size screens&ndash;&gt;
         <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
         &lt;!&ndash; all normal size screens &ndash;&gt;
         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />-->
         <!-- all large size screens - at 4" to 7" -->
         <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
         <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
         <!-- all extra large size screens - at 7" to 10" -->
         <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
         <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
         <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="640" />
     </compatible-screens>

    <application
        android:name=".application.NoteApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_app_logo"
        android:label="${appName}"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MediaListActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/screen_list_media_title"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MediaTextActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/screen_media_text_title"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MediaImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/screen_media_image_title"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MediaAudioActivity"
            android:label="@string/screen_media_audio_title"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MediaVideoActivity"
            android:label="@string/screen_media_video_title"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MediaDrawActivity"
            android:label="@string/screen_media_drawing_title"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/screen_settings_title"/>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <provider
            android:name=".database.NoteAppProvider"
            android:authorities="com.nouveal.note.NoteProvider" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

By the way, my coworker compiled it on android studio 1.4 and it worked, so...

Comment: Have you taken a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: Yeh I did it, but somehow it wasn't enough, I found out a way out though. Had to delete some repositories and reboot the PC. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it can't find your Activity: `com.nouveal.note.ui.activities.MainActivity`. If you have moved thing around, make sure to update your `manifest.xml` file to reflect the new package structure.

This error doesn't seem to be related to `Gradle` though.

Comment: I haven't move anything around though, and my manifest seems to fit the package (I haven't changed it either)

Comment: Can you please post your manifest? Just to see how you're registering the activity

Answer (score 0):

According with your error log I suppose you have a devices as my LG Stylus 3 Android 7.0, in which when you press and move app from desktop to the trash, app does not removed from device. See [my accepted answer on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249317/753575) for details.