# How do I pass data from sqlite database to another activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, bundle

I have a database with for Columns {id,eng,kurd,ar} and I have populated a listview from it that shows only {eng} from the databse. I want to pass the {eng,kurd,ar} which have the same {id} when the user clicks an item in the listview, but when I click an item my app crashes, but everything else works fine there is no error in non of the other classes[adapter,sqliteopenhelper]

**MainActivity.class**

```
package com.rawa.rawadict;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Adapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Item> myList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ListView myListView;
    Databasehelper myDbHelper = new Databasehelper(this);
    String engRes,kurdRes,arRes;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDatabase();
            myDbHelper.openDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.QueryData("select * from zankodict");
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Item itemm = new Item();
                    itemm.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                    itemm.setEng(cursor.getString(1));
                    myList.add(itemm);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.single_row, myList);
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lView);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView text_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tid);
            String sel_id = text_id.getText().toString();
            Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.QueryData("SELECT * FROM zankodict WHERE id =" + sel_id);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        engRes = cursor.getString(1);
                        kurdRes=cursor.getString(2);
                        arRes= cursor.getString(3);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            // create intent to start another activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
            // add the selected text item to our intent.
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("eng",engRes);
            extras.putString("kurd",kurdRes);
            extras.putString("ar",arRes);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }) ;


    }
}
```

**Result.class**

```
package com.rawa.rawadict;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView etView2,ktView2,atView2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result_view);
        etView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etextView2);
        ktView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ktextView2);
        atView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.atextView2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String enG = extras.getString("eng");
        String kurD = extras.getString("kurd");
        String aR = extras.getString("ar");
        etView2.setText(enG);
        etView2.setText(kurD);
        etView2.setText(aR);
        }
    }
```

I want to pass the Bundle to Result.class

Comment: You say it crashes, please add your Logcat output so we can see the crash error.

Comment: brother it gives me this error Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: I have also tried the technique in this link but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to passing data from activity to activity and particularly from your database is to pass an (id) as an intent extra then when you arrive at the destination activity, extract it and use it to query your database based on that id.

This will reduce the amount of data you will have to pass through your intent instance.

If you only want to pass 3 items however, you can use intent extras instead of a Bundle like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
intent.putExtra("eng",engRes);
intent.putExtra"kurd",kurdRes);
intent.putExtra("ar",arRes);

startActivity(intent);
```

To extract this in your Results activity;

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String enG = intent.getExtras().getString("eng");
String kurD = intent.getExtras().getString("kurd");
String aR = intent.getExtras().getString("ar");
```

I hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: He is passing as a bundle; not directly as an extra

Comment: Essentially the same thing. This will not solve any errors

Comment: @Eenvincible this is the same thing that I have done? what do you mean by error log, since I'm new to android development. thnx

Comment: When your app crashes, there is a cause printed out in your IDE console! That is the error log;

Comment: I thought u had something else in mind, by the way Thnx.