# Activity Not found in Oreo

Tags: android

Android starting activity not found while running the app. I have tested on other devices and it's working fine but not on Android Oreo.

```
 <application
    android:name=".network.NetworkController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

here is error

```
Error: Activity class {com.alch.outfi.outfi/com.alch.outfi.outfi.activities.SplashActivity} does not exist.
```

here is theme style.

```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

> Note: I have tried invalidate-cache and restart android studio, plus rename activity and then revert it but same issue.

Comment: have you try to invalidate-cache and restart android studio

Comment: @NileshRathod yes  i have tried it. but same issue

Comment: Build > Clean project, if that doesn't work then invalidate cache or refactor the activity name twice (once to a temp name, then back to the original)

Comment: There are a lot of potential solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist

try them all

Comment: @ZUNJAE I have renamed it and then revert it to original name but the issue still persists. is there anything new in android 8 for Manifest or permissions?

Comment: Are you using **apply plugin: 'android-library'** in build.gradle file?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed  I am using  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using a splash screen in android o. It was caused by the custom theme I was using before O. Are you using a custom theme for that activity?

If so, this solution might help you.

The custom theme had this code

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
```

but android O seems to crash with it so try this solution that I used to solve my issue

Create a new value-v26/styles.xml then add the code below in that xml

```
<style name="Splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowSplashscreenContent">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
```

Replace the background drawable with your own.

Comment: @I have mentioned theme style , i have not used any drawable but just colors, so I think it is not issue in my applicaton