# Session 'app': Error Launching activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    >  02/08 01:22:34: Launching app
    >     $ adb push D:\Android\FarmNET\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
    > /data/local/tmp/com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet
    >     $ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet"
    >     Success
    >     APK installed in 767 ms
    >     $ adb shell am start -n "com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet/com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet.HomeActivity"
    > -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    >     Error while executing: am start -n "com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet/com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet.HomeActivity"
    > -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    >     Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
    > cmp=com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet/.HomeActivity }
    >     Error type 3
    >     Error: Activity class {com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet/com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet.HomeActivity}
    > does not exist.
    >     
    >     Error while Launching activity
```

I have this error when I'm trying to run my app on mobile but it works with the emulator. I tried to fix this disabling instant run. but it is not working for me.

here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPlBm.png)

here is the HomeActivity.java

```
package com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx;
import com.ishara11rathnayake.farmnet.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting");
}

/**
 * BottomNavigationView setup
 */
private void setupBootomNavigationView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupBootomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
}
```

}

I tried a lot of things. But anything did not work for me. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question. See the answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist