# Activity class {} does not not exist android 3.5.1(Instant run is no longer available)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am trying to create application but while debugging after several time I am getting error.
Error: Activity class {com.tectibet.loginapp/com.tectibet.loginapp.MainActivity} does not exist.I tried cleaning cache and restart,rebuild and clean.

I have tried changing manifest and build.gradle package name as well.
also I went through [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist/38755357) 
but it didt work out.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Application is not launching at all displaying error like activity is does not exist(even though i does).

> Error while executing: am start -n
>   "com.tectibet.loginapp/com.tectibet.loginapp.MainActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.tectibet.loginapp/.MainActivity } Error type 3 Error: Activity
>   class {com.tectibet.loginapp/com.tectibet.loginapp.MainActivity} does
>   not exist.