# Error: Activity class {.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: java, android

I tried to run my android application in my android device but it keeps saying that my Main Activity does not exist although my Main Activity class is there

I tried to create a new project then copied my previous codes and it worked for a while. But then it produced the same error again.

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.sms/com.example.sms.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.sms/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.sms/com.example.sms.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

There is already a intent-filter in may android manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I already tried to clean and rebuild project. But it still gets the same error. My android device's version is android 9.

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.sms;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etNumber, etMessage;
    Button btnSend;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
        btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void MyMessage() {

        String phoneNum = etNumber.getText().toString().trim();
        String spamMessage = "Hi";

        if (etNumber.getText().toString().equals("09152006203")) {
            if (!etNumber.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                ArrayList<String> sms = smsManager.divideMessage(spamMessage);
                smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNum, null,sms,null, null);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Message has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter number or message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Number is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch(requestCode){

            case 0:
                if(grantResults.length>=0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    MyMessage();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You do not have required permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

        if(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            MyMessage();
        }
        else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 0);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It is happening because your package name is having conflicts go to you main activity class copy it's package name and paste it into your manifest activity tag in place of .MainActivity

Comment: This has a lot of answer, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: @Mr.Patel the same error occurs :(

Comment: please post your activity code

Comment: Make sure the app's id, package are correct. Try to uninstall the current app in your device & `File > Invalidate caches / restart` from android studio, then run again.

Comment: @NamNH still the error occurs :(

Comment: @kam1234 hi. I edited my post. thank you :)

Comment: Well i guess you will need to create a new project try running that if it doesn't work issue issue is with your studio and if it work copy paste your code in new application!

Comment: @AngelEsguerra, hard to determine the root cause, maybe the android studio has some problems. Try to create new project with simple activity template, then run it. If it's not crashed, your `sms` code (maybe in gradle or somewhere) has problems, otherwise the android studio. (Note that use androidX like your sample)

Comment: @NamNH is possible to determine if the android studio is the problem? If it is, what could be the possible solution?

Comment: @AngelEsguerra, So, It depends. you can try to do something like reset the config, or remove the `.m2` folder, even remove some conflict plugin (if found)... But, the fastest way is just re-install android studio (make sure clean uninstall it first).

Comment: Are use try to create simple project like my comment above? does it work? If it works, android studio is still ok, just rework with your current project, because your code still simple & little :).

Comment: @AngelEsguerra how did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, was it resolved? =)

Answer (score 11):

you can delete the folder of **idea**,then restart your project.

Comment: Thankyou. You save my day. This is the simple answer.

Comment: Saved my day .. very helpful other solutions did not worked

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! That's the solution!!!

Comment: Where is that folder? I couldnt find it

Comment: The folder is hidden `.idea` in the root of your android project folder

Answer (score 9):

Can you try uninstalling app using following ADB command and re-run?

```
adb uninstall <your-apps-package-name>
```

Answer (score 4):

Had this in react native, all the above solutions did not work for me
while in root, I did `cd android`
then `./gradlew uninstallAll`
then after its done, cd out , run the project and the error was gone

Answer (score 3):

I have had this happen to me once when I enabled the Fingerprint / PIN lock on the AVD and ran the app afterwards.

I found I needed to unlock the device before running the app.

Comment: This was downvoted, but I upvoted it, because this was the case for me. My emulator was still locked at startup, and I got this error. Once I unlocked the emulator, the app ran fine without the misleading "MainActivity does not exist" error.

Comment: Same here, that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take the path:

tab Run / edit Configuration / tab general / Lunch Options / launch.

And select the default activity option.
If the problem does not resolve, select the Specified Activity option and select the MainActivity.

If the problem is resolved, it is likely that the activity path is in the wrong androidManifest. You can write the path completely in androidmanifest.

```
<activity android:name="path.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In the code above write the path of the activity instead of the word path.
And also go back app configurations and choose the default activity one again.

Comment: Works for me only with Specified Activity, with default the command `am start` is generated with a double path like `com.xyz/com.xyz.activity`. Any idea why?

Comment: @rwst, `com.xyz/com.xyz.activity` is not a double path, it represents the package and the class of that component, see [ComponentName docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName#unflattenFromString(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Add the `intent-filter` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=“.MainActivity”>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying. There is already a intent-filter in my android manifest but it still gets the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:name="com.example.sms.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: try all of these

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this response here [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist).

Also, another common problem is if you are running your app on a physical device that has multiple user accounts. E.g. Main User and A Guest User. In this case there might be a conflict if one user does not update their application. Follow the following steps;

1. Go to Settings.
2. Go to Apps.
3. Select your app.
4. Open the overflow menu on the top right and select Uninstall for all users.
5. Done. Try to install then launch your app again.

The other alternative, which is longer, is to uninstall the app while in one account, then switch accounts and uninstall in the other.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred to me and I solved it by renaming the package and using "clean project and rebuild project" ... then I shut down android stodio and restarted it then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this response here Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist.

Also, another common problem is if you are running your app on a physical device that has multiple user accounts. E.g. Main User and A Guest User. In this case there might be a conflict if one user does not update their application. Follow the following steps;

Go to Settings.
Go to Apps.
Select your app.
Open the overflow menu on the top right and select Uninstall for all users.
Done. Try to install then launch your app again.
The other alternative, which is longer, is to uninstall the app while in one account, then switch accounts and uninstall in the other.