# Error type 3 - Error: Activity class MainActivity does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've tried to re-create my project cause of this error, in emulator the error was solved, but it kept on android device. It is saying that my MainActivity does not exist.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795063/error-activity-class-mainactivity-does-not-exist) and tried all answers, but all failed.

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.test/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.test/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.test/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my MainActivity, basically the Navigation Drawer template from android studio:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_home), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happened after I uninstalled the app directly from android device.
To solve it, I ran:

> `adb devices` -- to get the connected devices list

followed by:

> adb -s **device android id** uninstall **package.name**

Then, I ran again in android device with success

**Edit:**
to clarify the bold texts:

**device android id** is one of id you'll get after type **adb devices**.
Typing it, you'll get a list of connected devices with the ids

**package.name** is the text on top of your kotlin/java files, after the "package", like com.yourname.appname

Comment: This worked for me
the bold type needs explanation -
-- 'device android id' is the device name that you get when you run the adb devices command
-- 'package name' is the top line of your MainActivity.java file - like - com.yourname.appname

Comment: @jday I edited my answer to explain about, thanks for feedback!

Comment: When i tried this, i got this error Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Activity class
> {**com.example.test**/**com.example.myapplication.MainActivity**} does not
> exist.

Use this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Where is your `MainActivity` located? Any screenshots to see? I've just created a project (Navigation Drawer template) and it seems to be working fine with `android:name=".MainActivity"`. Still need to check if your `MainActivity` exist in the `com.example.test` package or not. You were also giving the IDE the path to find MainActivity from this package: `com.example.myapplication` which your package name is: `com.example.test`