# Android studio runs my application without installing the app

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to make an application using Android studio 3.6.3 and my phone to test it. I had a problem and I thought it was a good idea to uninstall the app, but now, Android studio doesn't recognize that the app does not exist on my phone and it tries to run the `MainActivity.class` file.
The error is:

> 05/27 21:03:30: Launching 'MainActivity' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7.
>
> $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.liteshop20/com.example.liteshop20.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.liteshop20/com.example.liteshop20.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.liteshop20/.MainActivity }
> Error type 3
> Error: Activity class {com.example.liteshop20/com.example.liteshop20.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity

How can i trick it to reinstall the app properly?

Comment: Have you tried the solution on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)?

Comment: Yes, I already did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it going at right side Grandle>MyApp>Tasks>install>UninstallRelease
and then Run the App again so it builds properly.