# Can't build Android Studio project on my phone after deleting app from it

Tags: android-studio, build

Can't build Android Studio project on my phone after deleting app from it.

I built the app on my phone and then deleted it and now I can't run the app from Android Studio, I get this error :

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.example/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.example/com.example.example.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

I tried Cleaning the Project and rebuilding it, it didn't work.

I tried Making the project, it didn't work.

I tried extracting the apk from the emulator and installing it on my phone, it didn't work.

How could I rebuild it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem simply Build the apk and install it on your phone and then it'll work