# Activity class does not exists

Tags: android

Activity class `com.example.me/com.example.me.SplashActivity` does not exist. after installing the app through USB debugging I am getting error.

Comment: Are you able to post both code sample code and Logcat stacktrace?

Comment: Do you have declared your activity in your android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Activity class {com.example.me/com.example.me.SplashActivity}does not exist

I have faced this problem multiple times before, you can try following solution one always works for me

1. To clear Android Studio's cache and bring it out of its state of confusion, select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button.
2. **ActivityNotFoundException** This exception is thrown when a call to startActivity fails because the Activity cannot be found. Usually, this means you forgot to declare the Activity in your Manifest.
3. Sometimes your application gets disabled from settings. so In your mobile go to settings -> Apps -> yourApp -> undo disabled and uninstall -> now install from android studio and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeing this error often lately with Android Studio.   What works for me is to bring up a Terminal window and then uninstall the app using adb:

```
adb uninstall com.example.me
```

using your example.   In other words, `adb uninstall your.package.name`

If that fails to solve your problem then you can read through the mega thread for all the other possible solutions:

[Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)