# i uninstalled app in phone but i try to run my project using android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-apps-script, mvvm, android-virtual-device

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xmwr.jpg)

I deleted the app which I created but I deleted it on my phone and I tried running it again but it is showing error type 3. it is running in other phones but not on the photo I deleted.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem after refactoring.
This is what i did to resolve this issue:

Cleaned the Project
Deleted the Build directory
Restarted Android Studio
Rebuild the Project
Run
Optionally (Go to the files menu on android, click on "Invalidate Caches / Restart..." uninstall the app on your phone and try again)

see : [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)