# unable to re-install a deleted app, any suggestion?

Tags: android, debugging, reinstall

I am using android studio and I can not re-install an app previously deleted. I try to re-install it in debug mode by the usb cable. No problem to install it on a device which never had this app.

I have the following message:

Error while executing: am start -n "fr.x.x/fr.x.x.DeviceScanActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=fr.x.x/.DeviceScanActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {fr.x.x/fr.x.x.DeviceScanActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
Any idea?

Best regards
Mich

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeing this error often lately with Android Studio.   What works for me is to bring up a Terminal window and then uninstall the app using adb:

```
adb uninstall fr.x.x
```

using your example.   In other words, `adb uninstall your.package.name`

If that fails to solve your problem then you can read through the mega thread for all the other possible solutions:

[Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)