# Android Studio not installing app on physical device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to download the app I built on my phone through Android Studio, but when I try to do it I keep getting this error

[image]

It looks like its saying it's not finding the MainActivity, but I do have that activity and the app is installing on other phones. I turned on developer mode and USB debugging mode.

Can someone please help? I don't know how to fix this issue and I don't want to factory reset my phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: @lyncx it worked the first try, but then I uninstalled the app, turned off developer options and tried to install the app through google play but it wouldnt install it so I tried to go through the same steps as the link but it didnt work so I dont know what to do now

Comment: Which activity in the manifest file has LAUNCHER?

Comment: @blackapps the MainActivity has the launcher