# Flutter app is not runnig on physicial device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, terminal

If i try to run my App on my physicial device which is a Huawei Mate 20 lite it just doesnt work.´
I have the newest SDK. I upgraded all using ***flutter upgrade -force*** which worked fine.
Flutter Doctor says no issues found.
I already used ***flutter run -v*** in the terminal and the following is the output:

```
  E: activity (line=21)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.big_randomizer.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.big_randomizer.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=35)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.a
ndroid.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=45)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" (Raw: "io.flutter.em
bedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
                   E: intent-filter (line=49)
                     E: action (line=50)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=52)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUN
CHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=59)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
[  +14 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on SNE LX1.
[+749666 ms] executing: C:\Users\Public\AppData\platform-tools\adb.exe -s HYF0218821022991 shell am force-stop
com.example.big_randomizer
[ +445 ms] executing: C:\Users\Public\AppData\platform-tools\adb.exe -s HYF0218821022991 shell pm list packages
com.example.big_randomizer
[ +227 ms] Installing APK.
[  +19 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Users\Public\AppData\platform-tools\adb.exe -s HYF0218821022991 install -t -r
C:\Flutter\Projekte\big_randomizer\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
[+4339 ms] Performing Streamed Install
                    Success
[   +6 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk... (completed in 4,3s)
[  +32 ms] executing: C:\Users\Public\AppData\platform-tools\adb.exe -s HYF0218821022991 shell echo -n
6e220f6fa0e648db5c3caadcc686e97764a53fb9 > /data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.big_randomizer.sha1
[ +197 ms] executing: C:\Users\Public\AppData\platform-tools\adb.exe -s HYF0218821022991 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +254 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    08-27 15:49:11.640 I/PreDnsController(  605): canPreDnsQuery,persist.sys.predns is false!
[  +76 ms] executing: C:\Users\Public\AppData\platform-tools\adb.exe -s HYF0218821022991 shell am start -a
android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez
enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true com.example.big_randomizer/com.example.big_randomizer.MainActivity[ +245 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.example.big_randomizer/.MainActivity
(has extras) }

                    Error type 3
                    Error: Activity class {com.example.big_randomizer/com.example.big_randomizer.MainActivity} does not
                    exist.
[   +5 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

This is a copy of the last lines in the terminal in AndroidStudio. After that nothing happends.

Comment: PS: Yesterday it worked perfectly fine. After trying it today this error showed up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24241687/9722336

Comment: This post is hidden. It was deleted 12 hours ago by Bhargav Rao♦.
I tried all of the suggested things on this site stackoverflow.com/a/24241687/9722336 but nothing worked. The thing that worked for me was to copy all of the code in a textdocument and make a complete new flutter project.

Now i reconnected the device and the same problem again. I am tired of doing copy paste code so pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

try execute that adb command again from terminal, and delete one by one the parameter to find what something wrong.

```
adb.exe -s HYF0218821022991 shell am start -a
android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez
enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true com.example.big_randomizer/com.example.big_randomizer.MainActivity
```

in my case, parameter `-a android.intent.action.RUN` that make activity not found.

so, the solution is to add action intent filter to android manifest:

```
<activity android:exported="true" android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

that's it, stuck/app not running resolved.