# When I use Flutter build apk, I get errors like this "a uses or overrides a deprecated API."

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, compiler-errors

I got this error after logging in with google.
I have looked for many solutions on the Internet for 2 days but none of them solved the problem. I opened a new project and transferred it there, but it didn't work either.
Some of the methods I use:

1-flutter clean,flutter build apk

2-flutter run -verbose

3-Delete Android/.gradle

4-dart fix --dry-run,dart fix --apply

[image: When i run "flutter build apk" i get this error]

[image: i run "flutter run -v"]

[image: i run "flutter run -v"]

[image: i run "flutter run -v"]

[image: i run "flutter run -v"]

[image: My files]

pubspec.yml code

```
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.14
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.17
  firebase_core: ^1.16.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.15
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: ^5.3.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.5
  path: ^1.8.0
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - image/lgscreen.png

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
 
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are warnings of the Gradle compiler plugin. It checks whether your code (or code of your dependencies) uses deprecated function calls at some point.

In your example, the code which uses deprecated features is part of libraries provided by Google.

Deprecation means, that the provider of a specific library emphasizes on not using a specific method as it may be removed in future releases.

There is not much you can do, if the message relates to code that you don't maintain. You could inform the maintainer of the library, though.

The build seems to succeed. During runtime, there seems to be an issue with the MainActivity – there are multiple reasons why this happens:

- [Flutter app is not runnig on physicial device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954898/flutter-app-is-not-runnig-on-physicial-device)
- [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: The error was not resolved, but instead of vs code, I was able to generate apk in android studio.