# Random error while trying to run my app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this error after trying to run my project after I had created another one before to attempt something:

```
01/24 19:14:48: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 30.
Install successfully finished in 412 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.wolfix/com.app.wolfix.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.wolfix/com.app.wolfix.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.wolfix/com.app.wolfix.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.wolfix/com.app.wolfix.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Why does it say "`Error: Activity class {com.example.wolfix/com.app.wolfix.MainActivity} does not exist.`" if I have a MainActivity class?

This is really weird because it didn't happen before but started happening now...

I have no idea, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't, there's so many steps, I think I did them in the wrong order.

Comment: Did you recently update Android Studio or upgrade Gradle? as i'm getting the same and i suspect doing that was the culprit

Comment: To my knowledge, no, I didn't update it. Maybe it auto updated, but I don't know why that's happening.

Answer (score 0):

If Package Name Is Different Then This Type Of Error Occurs

Check Package Name In All The Activity & build.gradle & Manifest.

Comment: My Package Name is correct, at least I think it is. I have the app folder name and the folder with the classes on it, and except in the gradle, they all have the same name. I changed it in the gradle but that didn't fix the issue. The MainActivity is not mispelled either.
I don't know if I there is a step-by-step guide that can fix this specific problem, because by removing builds and rebuilding the program, I think I messed it up even more.

Answer (score -1):

So I got this exact error after upgrading Android Studio and Gradle. Deleting (or at the very least renaming) the .idea folder fixed the issue and cleaned up a lot of files that seemed to be detritus left over from older versions.

My suspicion is there's an upgrade issue from some versions of android studio to the new one

Comment: I tried removing the .idea folder but I just can't seem to find it, or at least I don't know how to make it editable.

Comment: Ok, I guess you meant in the actual files in the PC, I found it.

Comment: I removed them, but now it tells me that my gradle version is 6.8 and that it needs to be 7.0.2...