# Android Studio gets package name wrong when running .apk

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

I changed my package name from com.mycompany.myapplication to com.mycompany.testapp.

Everything builds fine but when I try to run it on the emulator, I get:

> The session was restarted
>   Target device: NexusS [emulator-5554]
>   Uploading file
>       local path: /home/antony/AndroidStudioProjects/testappProject/testapp/build/apk/testapp-debug-unaligned.apk
>       remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.mycompany.myapplication
>   Installing com.mycompany.myapplication
>   DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.mycompany.myapplication"
>   pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.mycompany.myapplication
>   Success
>
> Launching application: com.mycompany.myapplication/com.mycompany.testapp.MainActivity.
>   DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.mycompany.myapplication/com.mycompany.testapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mycompany.myapplication/com.mycompany.testapp.MainActivity }
>   Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class {com.mycompany.myapplication/com.mycompany.testapp.MainActivity} does not exist.

Note the remote path ^^^ is wrong.

If I go to the emulator, I can start the app from the menu, it's just that I get this error when i try to run the app from Android Studio.

I also see in logcat, on the top-right, the drop-down offers me "No Filters" or "app:com.mycompany.myapplication".  So I can't even debug properly.

Where are these references to com.mycompany.myapplication coming from, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Check your manifest file

Comment: Somewhere along the line you changed the package name from `com.mycompany.myapplication` to `com.mycompany.testapp` -- fix your manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Why have I been voted down?  There are *no* references to com.mycompany.myapplication anywhere in the project, including in AndroidManifest.xml.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try looking at your run configuration to see if you specified it there.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the run configuration already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll answer, just in case anyone else gets stuck with this.  Strangely enough, restarting Android Studio solved the problem.  Nothing more complicated, nothing less obvious.

Comment: I have just run into this issue after changing my package name of an app. Restarting Android Studio (even with invalidating caches) did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Restarting didn't help, but re-importing the project did.

Comment: restart android studio didn't help for me too. But 'sync project with gradle files' did help.

Comment: Consider marking my answer as correct since @正宗白布鞋 confirmed it (most likely) wasn't restarting Android Studio that fixed it. I believe it worked to restart Android Studio because your gradle had to sync itself.

Comment: Another problem I am facing when I updated my Android Studio to 2.1.

Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.sition.diggintemp/com.example.sition.diggintemp.StartActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity

That is resolved after restart.

Answer (score 98):

I tried to restart Android Studio but the problem still existed.

Then the **solution** works with me.

1. Remove the directory `~/.gradle/caches/`. It's OK to do this while Android Studio is opened.
   (Refer [pm installing wrong package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785334/pm-installing-wrong-package-name))
2. Press "Sync project with Gradle files" icon on Android Studio
3. Run the project and the remote path will be correct.

Comment: Restarting, Sync Project, Invalidate Caches didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks!

Comment: Usually I don't let myself write chatty comments, BUT FOR GOD'S SAKE HOW IT CAN EVEN WORK? Many thanks!

Comment: this worked for me, randomly it happened, randomly it worked. Seems like gradle is still quite buggy,  been having alot of problems with it

Comment: you should use `./gradlew cleanBuildCache` to delete the gradle cache

Comment: Lifesaver sir! Thank you for sharing this, was tearing my hair out trying to resolve!

Comment: this is so f*cked up! spend an hour trying to figure out why my code changes are not working! (I temporarily changed app namespace to app2). then cleaned up and uninstalled both old and new version of app and then I got this on fresh launch! thanks for sharing

Comment: Restarting Android Studio after removing `~/.gradle/caches` was necessary in my case.

Answer (score 84):

Here is how I solved it. Very simple.

Click the **'Sync Project with Gradle Files'** button at the top of the window.

[image: 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' button screenshot]

Look for this button if you're using **newer version of Android Studio**:

[image: 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' button in newer AS screenshiot]

[image: 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' button in latest AS screenshiot]

Comment: This works for me as well. But shouldn't this be considered as a bug in Android Studio that needs to be fixed in the future? Just curious.

Comment: For me worked 3rd image(solution - Sync project with gradle files)

Comment: remove .gradle folder, restart IDE and sync gradle files and restart IDE again and restart react native project worked for me :D idk if less IDE restarts would work, but hey, it's black magic. go for it 

Answer (score 30):

I Did all mentioned things but no effect. Then I found something in **build.gradle** file and changed it as per my new package. It worked for me.

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.*****.newPackageId"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 20
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when the `versionCode` needed updating. Thanks. It seems that editing the package name and `versionCode`/`versionName` is done through `build.gradle` and not through the manifest! The "Merged Manifest" is what is used in the APK AFAICS.

Comment: This did it for me! Thanks so much.

Comment: After all other methods didn't work, this method finally worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Clearing the cache and restart worked for me.

Go to Android Studio's File menu and select Invalidate Caches / Restart... option

Answer (score 2):

In new version of AndroidStudio, such as 0.9.1, this solution works with me:

1) remove ~/.greadle/2.1/taskArtifacts
2) clean project
3) run the project

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. **None** of the solutions above helped me, so I am posting another solution, which helped me.

The problem appeared after I deleted my application 'by hand' on my smartphone.

I went to settings->apps. There was my app with 'Installed not for this user' (or something similar)
The solution was to **delete for all users in apps' settings**. (This was not done when I had deleted the app using main menu)

Answer (score 1):

What I finally did, is change the 'application ID' in the build.gradle, build and launch. Then remove the apps from the phone and revert the application ID back

Comment: Thanks ! this worked for me - change the applicationId in 'defaultConfig' then 'synchronize' and then 'Invalidate cache/restart' This did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

If your App is getting the Same name as your MainActivity and you have tried eve, try to remove

> android:label="MyMainActivity"

tag from Mainactivity, then run your app. That worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

None of this solutions above worked for me, but this did:

Refactor the package's name like:

```
com.name.examplename
```

Change to:

```
com.name.examplename2
```

Change your application ID with the new name of the package:

```
applicationId "com.name.examplename2"
```

Finally, go to:

> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Wait for android studio to restart, run your application again and get happy!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that some of my .xml files (particularly AndroidManifest.xml) had their headers changed somehow.

Problematic header:

```
<?xml code="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Change this to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Notice how  the problematic header shows `code="1.0"` instead of `version="1.0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried deleting taskArtifacts folder, invalidating,... nothing worked.

What end up working for me as forcing a Gradle Sync solved for me. (Just added a empty new line in the build.gradle to make it ask me to Sync and after the Sync it worked).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

- Check the manifest first of all.
- Then Check your gradle files
- And finally, it might be worth checking the 'test' and 'androidTest' java files.

If you don't know what to do to these files, then look at the more complete answers above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build APK.
2. Transfer it to device.
3. Install it.
4. Now you can install the same application using ADB.