# EmptyThrowable: The APK file *.apk does not exist on disk

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is an Android application using gradle. After clicking <kbd>Run</kbd>, I found `APP_V1.3.4_2016-02-22_`**`11:30:29`**`_google_play.apk` in `outputs/apk`, but the event log says:

> 11:30:31 EmptyThrowable: The APK file /.../WorkSpace/Android/.../app/build/outputs/apk/APP_V1.3.4_2016-02-22_**11:30:14**_google_play.apk does not exist on disk.
>
> 11:30:32 Session 'app': Error Installing APK

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def releaseTime() {
    return new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss",
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+08:00"))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 29
        versionName "1.3.4"
        manifestPlaceholders = [SOME_CHANNEL_VALUE: "some_channel"]
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {}

        release {
            // ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
        }

        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->

                def time = releaseTime()

                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def apk = output.outputFile
                    def endFileName = "${time}_${variant.productFlavors[0].name}.apk"

                    if (apk != null &&
                        apk.name.endsWith('.apk') &&
                        !apk.name.endsWith('${endFileName}')) {
                        def fileName = "APP_V${defaultConfig.versionName}_${endFileName}"
                        output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, fileName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        google_play {
            manifestPlaceholders = [SOME_CHANNEL_VALUE: "google_play"]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
}
```

So is there any wrong with `releaseTime()`?

Comment: Yes, do you see the exact times? One is 11:30:14. the other one is 11:30:29 (which is what you found but different from what the computer expects)

Comment: @ucsunil Thanks for your reply. I noticed the difference between the two times, but I have no idea on solving it :( I don't know how does gradle find the apk.

Comment: Suggest to use git date instead:
ex. "git show -s --format=%ci"
and more here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/build.gradle
about pretty format : https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my case the problem was that the name of the apk to be installed was cached, so everytime I tried running the app, an apk with today's date was generated but when installing, Android Studio looked for an apk file with an old name. The solution was to click *Sync Gradle* and then *Build* > *Rebuild Project*. You may also want to delete folders *app/apks* and *app//build/outputs/apk* previously.

Comment: worked for me when I tried to rename apk automatically with current date

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a problem for the android plugin version. i changed it from `File->Project Structure->Project` and changed the `Android Plugin Version` to any previous version. it may be any version of Android Studio. Basically Android Plugin Version is the version of your Android Studio Software version. It's not mandatory to keep the android plugin version same as android studio software version. you can give it any previous version of android studio you have installed.

Comment: finally a solution that actually worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This happened on me because I removed all the "Extras" tools under "Standalone SDK Manager" and re-download the necessary tools only.
*I'm not sure is this related to the problem or not.

Anyway I tried both *Sync Gradle* and *Rebuild Project* doesn't solve the problems.

> *EmptyThrowable*: The APK file D:\...\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.

I solved it by clicked:

> *Build > Build APK*

**Working solution for me.**

Comment: Tried everything and it took me one entire day!! Build > Build APK did it! Unbelievable!!

Comment: every time we need to build apk, is there any better solution?

Comment: @UmaAchanta I don't think there are any alternative without building apk. If you are concerning about the time taken of apk build, the newer version of Android Studio seems to have a greatly reduced build time. (Based on my previous experiences, but I don't remember which one.)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the things like

- Delete folders app/apks and app//build/outputs/apk previously
- SyncGradle and Rebuild Project
- lintOptions {
              abortOnError false
          }

but got issue resolved by Clicking on **Build>Build APK**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and nothing suggested above helped: neither clean/build nor restart Android Studio/PC. The problem was that there was locked file .gradle/buildOutputCleanup/cache.properties. Just removing cache.properties.LOCK file and then cleaning the project fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Gradle is calculating the time twice - once when building the apk, then again while trying to install it.

Do not calculate time again when you are creating the endFileName. Just do:

```
def endFileName = time + "_${variant.productFlavors[0].name}.apk"
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why it runs twice? Thank you!

Comment: `releaseTime()` is not being called twice, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Android Studio worked for me. Hopefully same will work for you.
Else have a look at below link.
[The APK file does not exist on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk)

Edit- If this doesn't work , use Invalidate Cache / Restart in File menu. Hope this helps.