# Error while launching app, apk does not exist on disk

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the error which i am getting while running my app and installing it in emulator

```
The APK file E:\project path\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK
```

I have tried with clean and rebuild, also by restarting Android Studio but it doesn't help me out.

**Note :** It is just hello world program, and i am not getting any error in message or log also.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545579/emptythrowable-the-apk-file-apk-does-not-exist-on-disk) but didn't work for me.

Comment: `Invalidate Cache / Restart `

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya tried that also, but no luck

Comment: You need to Stop the ANTIVIRUS Software if Installed,
Some antivirus treat .APK file as harmful software

Comment: @Ronish there is no ANTIVIRUS s/w in my system, and for information i have other projects running successfully.

Comment: I suggest you put your project in a directory with no spaces

Comment: @Bipi there is no space in project directory, `project path` is just dummy text as i cannot mention my original project directory name.