# Unable to run project after finishing build AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In my project i was able to build successfully but when i try to run the project i am getting the following error

```
 Gradle build finished in 56s 112ms

 EmptyThrowable: The APK file /home/dell/git/my-seat-app-current/App/build/outputs/apk/App-dev-debug.apk does not exist on disk.

 Launching App
 The APK file /home/dell/git/my-seat-app-current/App/build/outputs/apk/App-dev-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK
```

When i click on empty Throwable it will open a dialog with below details

```
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.DeployApkTask.perform(DeployApkTask.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

Comment: just follow these links to rebuild build or refresh
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it work fine when i replace below line in gradle

```
  defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.ext.testMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.ext.testTargetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "mytestApp" +
                getSprintVersion() +
                getProductionVersion() + "-" +
                getDate() + "-" + getTime());
       }
```

with

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.ext.testMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.ext.testTargetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "mytestApp");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to sync your Gradel, click the round blue arrows at the top left of Android studio, when you hover over it it says synchronize [image]

Or you can right click you Gradel projects in the projects panel and select synchronize gradel.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still unable to run despite syncing the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if your app has any jni/native parts, but I experienced this today using the latest experimental gradle plugin (0.8.0-alpha3).

Simply dropping back to alpha2 fixed it for me:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.0-alpha2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to follow these steps:

1-check build variants

2-do clean

3-file -> invalidate
    caches/restart