# APK File doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.1

I recently updated my android studio and have started getting this error:

> The APK file \app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk does not exist on
> disk. Error while Installing APK

This is quite frustrating as I have tried everything I have come across online and nothing has worked.

As far as I'm aware the path to the app-debug.apk is correct and it does exist. If anyone has some insight please help!

## TEMPORARY FIXES

1. Running it in release mode does work. ~Thanks to [Umer Farooq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5476346/umer-farooq)
2. Running it with a custom build variant also works and gives a little more freedom than just release mode. ~Thanks to [Prashant Shable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7047583/prashant-sable)

These fixes are nice to get your current project running, but doesn't fix the original problem. Give these a try if nothing else works for you and you are sick of seeing the error. :)

## PERSONAL FIX

I'd love to say it was complicated, but it really wasn't. I had a ' (special character) in my Users folder name. Apparently this was causing the problem. This was pointed out in the comments of the Answer by [Umer Farooq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5476346/umer-farooq).

## Final Remarks

I wanted to say thanks to everyone for the help. I think all these answers will make a nice reference for future AS users with this problem.

Comment: click Build-->Build apk, it will show a popup on left when build get ready with link to apk

Comment: @Bills No luck on that either.

Comment: Add Gradle Console and event log in question

Comment: Have you try unplug the device?

Comment: I couldn't find any problem but found `APK(s) generated successfully.
            Show in Explorer` click on Show in Explorer

Comment: It just took me to the same path it thinks doesn't exist. I'm going to try a complete wipe/uninstall of AS and any related files then try reinstalling it. Hopefully it's just an issue caused by the remnants of the previous AS.

Comment: Delete build folders and reimport your project.

Comment: @PrashantSable Still same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you setup any productFlavors in your build.gradle file? If not try with creating a new debug flavor.

Comment: @PrashantSable I was able to get a custom Build Variant working with debugging active. At the very least it's a fix, but the default debug build still has that same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it in a release mode to get your apk file ...

Comment: While this does work to run it in release mode, it does not help me with debug. I did try making a new debug key and point to it in the project structure but it still has the same issue.

Comment: delete a build folder in your app manually and then clean the project and rebuild it ... Hopefully it works..

Comment: Have you checked your path for apk file ?? It must not contain any special character

Comment: Apparently a windows 10 update had altered my user folder and added 's-PC to the end. I hate to say this was the problem, but I think you're right. Once I got rid of it and changed the various android paths it seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] the clarification comments to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Manually Delete apk folder from the Project Directory then clean and rebuild project in  android studio

Project folder ---> build---->outputs--->apk (delete the folder)

Clean and rebuild in AndroidStudio

Comment: Still same issue. :(

Comment: then  invalidate caches and restart android studio

Comment: No luck on that either.

Answer (score 0):

Click the button marked in red color.

[image]

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk)

Comment: Sadly I've already looked over this page and it didn't do anything for me.