# The APK file /Users/...../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk does not exist on disk

Tags: android-studio

When I'm trying to test my android application on my android phone I get an error saying:

> The APK file /Users/..../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
>   Error while Installing APK

Also my Event logs are:

> 3:21:33 AM Gradle build finished in 57s 37ms
>   3:21:33 AM Session 'app': Error Installing APK

But I can clearly see the file /Users/..../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk after run and also my device is successfully connected in usb debugging mode on.

I'm using android studio 2.2

I have tried [The APK file does not exist on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk) all these methods too but it doesn't help me out in my case.
Also if I choose installDebug in Gradle properties (:app-->install-->installDebug) while running then app automatically get installed on my device, in that case my Event logs are:

> 3:25:02 AM Executing tasks: [installDebug]
>   3:25:12 AM Gradle build finished in 10s 70ms

Desperately looking for help, thanks.

Comment: Solved the problem, by removing special character in my app-debug.apk file path

Answer (score -2):

I personally am not familiar with Android Studio, but did you try refreshing the page and trying to build the APK again? You could also maybe double-check if the file saved to a different folder.

Comment: Hey Vivianne Thanks for help, I have tried all the different ways tried by folks in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk they have already included page refreshing and synchronising techniques.

Comment: OK. Glad I could try to help let me know what you find out