# Android Studio not generating APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a strange problem that just started with an existing Android Studio 2.3.3 project.

The build process is not automatically generating an APK, in this case app-debug.apk Log shows build is successful, but no APK anywhere in the project directory tree.  Manually selecting Build / Build APK works fine, however.

This is a problem when I change the source and click run.  The build process is successful, but then get "Error Installing APK" into the emulator (because the APK does not exist).

This problem only happens on the one project, and I was playing around with Espresso earlier.  My guess is I changed a setting somewhere, I just cannot figure out which one.  What do I need to change to have the APK generated automatically again?  build.gradle included.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 2
    versionName "0.0.2"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("/home/user/keystore/keystore.jks")
        storePassword "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        keyAlias "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        keyPassword "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Have you done File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart` . It did not help.

Comment: Did you try doing a clean and then build again? Also check the app/build/output/ folder and see if you can find an apk folder with your app apk inside it

Comment: Yes - I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but an APK is not created anywhere.  As I wrote in my question manually clicking Build/Build APK does work, and creates the APK in the build/outputs/apk directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try below solution -

At right side of Android studio you have a gradle option click on that and then click the refresh icon and then check build.

More details follow below link -

[apk not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Due to many dependencies in `Build.gradle` android studio takes too much time and then said Request time out. So have a look into `Build.gradle`.
Do these steps.

**First Method**: try to minimize the dependencies

**Second Method**: Add MultiDEX `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'` this is for androidX.

**Third Method**: Make class `public class ApplicationDelegate extends MultiDexApplication { }` then add in Android Manifest File like this in Application tag

```
<application
        android:name=".ApplicationDelegate"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Answer (score 0):

My Android Studio does it all the time so I came up with a workaround. Instead of going to Build > Build APK. I simply run the app.

After running the app if you go to build > output > apk in your project directory, you will find your APK over there. Android Studio rarely throws an error when you run the app.

**EDIT**
This APK does NOT work on physical devices I dont know what the reason is. It runs on emulators though.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right with the key, maybe it is not on the path... A studio does not report anything then (simply does not build bundle). Click on the folder icon in the key alias field it will be an error if the key is not on the path (fastest check).

Answer (score 0):

My Android studio was not creating apk file. So I uninstalled Android studio. Then deleted manually, .gradle folder and AndroidstudioApplications folder, and again installed Android studio. It worked for me.