# Android Studio 3.1 - Exception in plugin Android Support

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I have updated to the latest version of Android Studio (3.1) and I get the following error when I try to run my app. It was working with no problems before the update. I have also uninstalled Android Studio and downloaded the latest version from the official website. Nothing has changed.

```
null java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.InstantRunNotificationTask.<init>(InstantRunNotificationTask.java:64)
        at com.android.tools.idea.fd.InstantRunBuildAnalyzer.getNotificationTask(InstantRunBuildAnalyzer.java:188)
        at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidLaunchTasksProvider.getTasks(AndroidLaunchTasksProvider.java:122)
        at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:102)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced the exact same problem, I was afraid I broke something... I fixed it by cleaning and rebuilding the project (I had disabled instant run as suggested here before but I guess that was not necessary as I enabled it again after cleaning and rebuilding the project and worked just fine...).

**Build -> Clean Project**

**Build -> Rebuild Project**

I am not sure if rebuilding would be necessary, I did both steps and it worked fine, maybe just cleaning the project would have been sufficient.

Hope that helps!!

**EDIT**

Nice, one more thing. When I solved the problem depicted here I found another problem, when I clicked run the apk was not being created and I solved it with my answer on that other thread:

[The APK file does not exist on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524942/5428997/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that as well, later. Hope it works, because instant run is a great feature.

Comment: For anyone having this issue for the Android version that I mentioned. This also worked for me for Android Studio 3.4.2.

Answer (score 3):

Disable "Instant Run" Work for me.

> > File>>Setting>>Build,Execution,Deployment>>Instant Run

Uncheck "Enable Instant Run......."

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. In my case Android Studio deleted all the "android:id"s from layout files.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got solution is following:

1) Disable the "Instant Run". Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Uncheck -> apply -> OK

2) Build -> Clean and Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

Change the buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' to '27.0.2' in build module then revert back and sync gradle

Answer (score 0):

I faced in android studio 3.5 in this same issue .Just delete android studio 3.5 and I install 3.4.1 .Then there is no error.