# Android Studio “IDE error occured” after update

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My app worked fine but after running it a few times I got a problem with the gradle build. ([Android Studio: failed to complete gradle execution, cause is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27407855/8516624)) i've restarted my computer and before trying to fix the issue it showed me that I have an update for a few thing in android studio. After the update it asked me to update some versions of implementation in the gradle and then the "com.google.gms:google-services" version in the project gradle. After doing so I get an error saying "IDE error occured" when trying to do a build.
The exception is occuring in the Android Support Plugin.

The exception details:

```
null                                      
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.InstantRunNotificationTask.<init>(InstantRunNotificationTask.java:64)
at com.android.tools.idea.fd.InstantRunBuildAnalyzer.getNotificationTask(InstantRunBuildAnalyzer.java:188)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidLaunchTasksProvider.getTasks(AndroidLaunchTasksProvider.java:122)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:102)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' // google-services plugin


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.xxx.xxxxxx'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to Severiano Jaramillo Quintanar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523362/8516624)!

> I faced the exact same problem, I was afraid I broke something... I
>   fixed it by cleaning and rebuilding the project (I had disabled
>   instant run as suggested here before but I guess that was not
>   necessary as I enabled it again after cleaning and rebuilding the
>   project and worked just fine...).
>
> **Build -> Clean Project**
>
> **Build -> Rebuild Project**
>
> I am not sure if rebuilding would be necessary, I did both steps and
>   it worked fine, maybe just cleaning the project would have been
>   sufficient.
>
> Hope that helps!!
>
> **EDIT**
>
> Nice, one more thing. When I solved the problem depicted here I found
>   another problem, when I clicked run the apk was not being created and
>   I solved it with my answer on that other thread:
>
> [The APK file does not exist on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524942/5428997/)

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio:

1. Go to File / Invalidate caches.. /
2. Then select both options and restart
3. After restarting of Android Studio your problem is solved out