# Running Android Test - The APK file "...-androidTest.apk" does not exist on disk

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

I'm attempting to run a specific android test (JUnit & Espresso), but get the following error:
[image: Error]

I'm executing the test as so (debug):
[image: Running Test]

The app is successfully installed and usable after the process.

The directory `/Users/user/Projects/kiwix-android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/` does not exist and is not created, let alone the `app-kiwix-debug-androidTest.apk` file itself.

My aim is to be able to debug (breakpoints etc.) individual tests on a real device.
All suggestions welcome!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk?answertab=active#tab-top) can help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Android Studio. The tests don't seem to get compiled before it attempts to install and run them. So, you need to compile them beforehand

```
./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest -x test
```

After you do this, you should be able to run/debug using Android Studio. Note that if you make any changes **in your test code**, you'll need to run the above command again.