# Android studio does not generate build

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to run on device  I got the following error

Program type already present: com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.zxing.ChecksumException, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

can anyone please help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The APK file does not exist on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk)

Comment: @BAAAZINGA : I have checked it and none of them solve my problem, it seems there is another library that use same dependencies and I do not know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Two of your dependencies are using different versions of the same class. Read more [in this explanation](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/77499230#comment7) or in the [official message](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes).