# AndroidStudio: Run Configuration Error: Default Activity not found

Tags: android

I was trying to rename the name of the package of my first android project (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842125/how-to-fix-activity-class-does-not-exist-error-in-android?)), but now I see an error in AndroidStudio:

```
Run Configuration Error: Default Activity not found
```

on the 'run' button. See this screenshot:

[image]

How to fix this in AndroidStudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your java files have the name of your package in the first line itself. For example:

```
package com.xyz.android;
```

Please change them too.

Comment: So the 'refactor' function of AndroidStudio does not work at all?

Comment: But it worked! And I only spend 100 minutes to rename my app! Great! I actually thought it would take a whole day...

Comment: I don't know much about the 'refactor' function. Great it worked though. :)