# Getting error when launching application in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I'm facing the following error:

> Error while executing: am start -n
>   "com.package/com.package.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN
>   -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>       Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.package/.SplashActivity
>   } Error type 3 Error: Activity class
>   {com.package/com.package.SplashActivity} does not exist.     Error
>   while Launching activity

So what can I do to resolve this issue

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.company.xyz">

    <application
        android:name="GoogleAnalyticsApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <!-- For Pushwoosh we have to set following code: -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have added Manifest file also in that you can see what I need to change and I am using push for notification.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**Edited** : com.company.xyz packagename which is same in other build.gradle and manifest

I have checked both files are having same package name and the application is running in all device but when i try to run it on OREO it not launching activity.

Comment: share your manifest file with question

Comment: could you add your manifest here,and also how did you add your SplashActivity to the Project??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package rename and error "Activity class does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180185/package-rename-and-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: add (android {
defaultConfig {  )   section from gradle

Comment: @ReazMurshed my question is different just look at the question once again.

Comment: Did you try clearing the caches in Android Studio? File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Answer (score 1):

OP, Have you found a solution for this?

I had the same issue using a splash screen in android o. It was caused by the custom theme I was using before O. Are you using a custom theme for that activity?

If so, this solution might help you.

The custom theme had this code

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
```

but android O seems to crash with it so try this solution that I used to solve my issue

Create a new value-v26/styles.xml then add the code below in that xml

```
<style name="Splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowSplashscreenContent">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
```

Replace the background drawable with your own.

The full detail of the solution is from this [post](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-splash-screen-for-api-26-and-below-7420d02904d1) by Omkar Amberkar

Answer (score 0):

make sure in android manifest file in your SplashActivity is call first like below code..

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"><!--activity is package name. hear pass your first activity to load app start-->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I think the activity entry is already in the manifest. I have already marked the question as a duplicate of another answer. From my point of view, I think the activity package has renamed and that doesn't have proper reflection in the manifest file which is causing the error. Please look closely in the error.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity class {com.package/com.package.SplashActivity} does not exist.`

I think the activity class package name or the manifest declaration along with the fully specified package name is missing in your case.